# Generated Attributes in Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

Is there a way to generate attributes using JavaScript in Jade?

In something, like EJS, one could do:

```
<div <?- bool ? 'attribute' : 'no attribute' ?>>
```

There is no equivalent in Jade, apparently. Sure I could do:

```
option(selected=bool)
```

And Jade would generate the appropriate HTML output for this attribute. But as far as I can tell, there is no way to write anything more complex than this.

The question isn't whether this would be needed; One could probably get by without this. However, is it possible in Jade and I'm just not aware?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact scenario, you have a few options.

If `'no attribute'` is trying to exclude `attribute`, you can [set it to `null` or `undefined`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#attributes) (though, as you already noted, `false` can also work):

```
div(attribute=condition ? 'value' : null)
```

If, however, your intent is attribute swapping, you can accomplish this with [embedded markup](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#html) and [interpolation](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#tag-text):

```
| <div #{bool ? 'attribute' : 'no-attribute'}>
```

Or, I believe you have to condition each separately:

```
div(attribute=bool, no-attribute=!bool)
```

There's also been some suggestions of specifying attributes from an object, such as [#664](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/664) which offers a possible alternative with `mixin`s.

Comment: Interesting. The only problem is that it's HTML not Jade. If I wanted to nest children for this element, how does it play in the indentation flow of the Jade template?